# How to identify if IE exhausted it's per domain connection limits

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

If IE is busy with page loading then it generally shows swirling icon instead of `favicon.ico`. But how to distinguish between following

1. Connection limits are reached and IE has not yet received all content
2. IE received response from all its requests but is busy rendering the page

Will IE a show busy icon if any JavaScript operation is not finished (mainly `onload` JavaScript call ?)

Thanks and regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 1):

In regards to "1.Connection limits are reached and IE has not yet received all content" this limitation is imposed in WinInet, I didn't even try to answer this question because almost all the ways I could think to even approach the problem(from within the page itself) involved methods that would further reduce the load time of the page. DanP's suggestion about Fiddler is a good one, what you could do is write an extension or some custom script for Fiddler that would log when TWO requests to the same host name were processing at any given time so you would have a log.  Otherwise it's a matter of eye-balling it in fiddler and just looking to see if two requests of the same host name are processing at the same time, but in general the requests finish so quickly that trying to get a good feel of this in fiddler by just watching the UI can be problematic.

In regards to "2.IE received response from all its requests but is busy rendering the page" it sounds like you want to know when the page is ready for the user to interact with it.  The fact of the matter is IE doesn't perform these tasks synchronously, it renders the page while it is downloading things, and the user can interact with the page while IE is still busy downloading.  So what I've done is included an example here that shows how you can tell when that spinner icon in the Internet Explorer tab switches to the favicon.  The spinner goes away when document.readyState == "complete", however the page is ready for the user to interact with it on document.readyState == "interactive" which happens to also be after the document.body.readyState == "complete", I don't know if document.body.readyState == " complete" is causative of document.readyState == "interactive" but they certainly appear to coincide.  However, if you did want to determine if everything was downloaded, every element in the DOM has a readyState property, you could potentially enumerate the DOM to check if every element has a readyState == "complete" to determine if every element was done downloading and rendering.

The sample html you can save to your computer and run, but if you run it from the local disk, IE will prompt you with the yello info bar, and you will need to right click to allow it to run the script.  When the html is run properly you should see javascript alerts, you will notice on the alert that says "document.readyState: interactive" that the spinner is still spinning, but when the alert that says "document.readyState: complete" you will notice the spinner icon has gone away.  Hope this helps.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        document.onreadystatechange = function(e)
        {
            alert("Document State: " + 
                             document.readyState + 
                             "\nBody State: " + 
                             document.body.readyState);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Test Content
<div id="placeToAddTo"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var obj = document.createElement("div");
        obj.innerText = "Div Number: " + i + " Document State: " 
                   + document.readyState + " Body State: " 
                   + document.body.readyState;
        document.getElementById("placeToAddTo").appendChild(obj);
    }
    alert("completed creating object");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the only way would be to look at something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - and then you can track exactly what IE is doing, and (fun times) make a count.

I can't think of any other ways, sadly.

Comment: Thanks danp. But do you think is there any programmatic way of getting the information like some javascript handlers to get the status of how many connections are busy , if connection pools exhausted , if javascript calls are in endless loop ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - I guess its a case of digging through msdn and seeing if there is any way of getting hold of this info. There might be some way you can hook into it with a little .net app or so.. but I'm just speculating. It sounds like the kind of thing that you shouldn't need to know, or could be resolved with client side code optimisation.